# Prevent ngCookies from escaping characters

Tags: angularjs, cookies

### Problem

I'm attempting to set a cookie with a serialized-object value, which looks something like:

```
var serializedObj = 'firstName=john&lastName=smith';
```

Native (works fine)

```
document.cookie = 'myObj=' + serializedObj;
// result: firstName=john&lastName=smith (fine)
```

Angular's `$cookies` (escapes characters)

```
$cookies.put('myObj', serializedObj);
// result: firstName%3Drichard%26lastName%3Dherman (wrong)
```

### Question

Is it possible to prevent `$cookies` from escaping these characters?

Answer (score 0):

The Angular $cookie function escapes your data when storing a cookie, and un -escape it when it is retrieved.

If you don't want this to happen, don't use the Angular implementation. You can simply set the cookie yourself using the native browser cookie API.

Comment: I appreciate you taking time to respond, but sadly your answer doesn't address the question at hand. I'd like to know *if* it's possible to prevent the escaping / un-escpaing.